# funnel chart labels out side

Tags: javascript, chart.js, angular-chart, chartjs-2.6.0

[image: i need that underline text]i had tried below code using "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels"
but  i m unable to get labels outside can anyone please help me out

```
pieceLabel: {
    render: 'label',
    fontColor: '#000',
    position: 'outside',
    segment: true
}

callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
        var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        return label + ': ' + datasetLabel + '%';
    }
}
```

and i had tried with datalabels also but no use

i need labels  outside which shown in screen shot  rounded with pencil

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz or a plunker for this?

Comment: yes i will provide